# How can I "alias" a URL path to a function?

Tags: cherrypy

I am using CherryPy, and in my class I have a attribute `suppliers`, no I also want to have a URL path `suppliers` that requests that attribute, obviously that doesn't work. But how to "alias" that path to prevent a 404?

```
class MyServer(object):
   def __init__(self, _suppliers):
      self.suppliers = _suppliers

   @cherrypy.expose
   @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
   def get_suppliers(self):
      return self.suppliers
```

I tried `expose(path="suppliers")` and `expose(alias="suppliers")` but both don't work.

I am using CherryPy 18.8.0.